# OpenMediaVault and RSync - SSH Key authentication

Tags: rsync

I installed an OpenMediaVault server. This server allows to configure some rsync pullings.

I'd like to pull some data from another server to my OMV server with rsync.

Let's call my OMV server the "A" server and my target (with files to pull) the "B" server.

I created a user called omv on the B server. I simply want to add the A server public SSH Key of my omv user to the B server. The purpose is to allow OpenMediaVault to make a rsync command without any password prompt.

But, on the A server, OpenMediaVault is running as a "service" user called openmediavault. It does not have home directory and it seems to be a different kind of user. So, I don't know where to generate my ssh keys on the A server so that OpenMediaVault can have an access when running rsync tasks.

I'm not closed to make a username/password authentication instead of ssh keys on OpenMediaVault side, but it does not seems to be allowed.

I'm a little bit lost. I guess I'm thinking the wrong way about it, because a lot of people have made it before I do, but I dont get the point...

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I just did not added my omv user in the AllowedUsers in the B server.

So, I added the line "AllowUsers root omv" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, and now it works well. I also generated the certificate in the "Certificates" section of OpenMediaVault.